# Error parsing twitter json response in android

Tags: android, json, twitter, lookup

I try to use Twitter Get users/lookup to look up users information. But I got some error in parsing the response json file. The request URI is: "https://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json?screen_name=nba". My code is:

```
public String getInternetData() throws Exception{
    String data = null;
    try {
        URI website = new URI("https://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json?screen_name=nba");
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.setURI(website);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        String str = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        try {
            JSONObject jouser = new JSONObject(str);
            data = jouser.getString("followers_count");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection: " +e.toString());
    }
    return data;
}
```

The response JSON content is

```
[
   {
      "notifications":false,
      "id":19923144,
      "profile_link_color":"177BC7",
      "profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1787324427\/National-Basketball-Association_normal.jpg",
      "profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/559347559\/12twitter_playoffs_0523.jpg",
      "id_str":"19923144",
      "following":false,
      "profile_use_background_image":true,
      "profile_image_url":"http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1787324427\/National-Basketball-Association_normal.jpg",
      "utc_offset":-18000,
      "friends_count":988,
      "profile_text_color":"333333",
      "time_zone":"Eastern Time (US & Canada)",
      "default_profile":false,
      "followers_count":5095414,
      "name":"NBA",
      "profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/brand_banners\/NBA\/1335482314\/live",
      "url":"http:\/\/www.nba.com",
      "profile_sidebar_border_color":"eeeeee",
      "created_at":"Mon Feb 02 19:04:42 +0000 2009",
      "protected":false,
      "listed_count":28499,
      "profile_background_tile":false,
      "contributors_enabled":true,
      "profile_sidebar_fill_color":"ffffff",
      "geo_enabled":false,
      "description":"News and notes directly from the NBA.",
      "location":"New York, NY",
      "is_translator":false,
      "show_all_inline_media":true,
      "statuses_count":28818,
      "follow_request_sent":false,
      "lang":"en",
      "profile_background_color":"000000",
      "default_profile_image":false,
      "verified":true,
      "favourites_count":15,
      "screen_name":"NBA",
      "profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/559347559\/12twitter_playoffs_0523.jpg"
   }
]
```

Then I got the error: *Error parsing data: org.json.JSONException: Value [{"location"......
Anybody has an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the response starts with `[` it means it is actually a JSON Array, not an object. Then, you will have to do something like this:

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(str);
JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(0);
String followersCount = jsonObject.getString("followers_count");
```

Comment: It does start with [. But I cant find the name for this array. Like in this file, what parameter should i replace for "pepe" in this expression: JSONArray array = new JSONArray(pepe) ?

Comment: pepe? What's pepe? What are you talking about?

Comment: You are right. This is a JSONArray, not a JSONObject. JSONArray array = new JSONArray(str); fix the problem. Thanks body!

Comment: Another question: how to judge the data type in the response JSON file? Like "followers_count":5414. How can I decide whether its an int or a long type?

Comment: Besides trying things like getInt or getLong and catching an exception there is no way (other than knowing the JSON data before hand).